# Bluetooth socket connect failed for Android 5.1

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I want to receive data from a hardware device through Bluetooth in Android 5.1, but I got the following errors:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: bt socket connect failed
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:317)
W/System.err:     at com.pda.bt.ConnectThread.run(ConnectThread.java:54)
E/error: bt socket connect failed
```

It just shows the error of `bt socket connect failed`. I tried to resolve the problem with various methods, but didn't work.

This is my code for `connect`:

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final BluetoothDevice mDevice;
    private final BluetoothSocket mySocket;
    private static final UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothAdapter adapter) {
        int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        BluetoothSocket _mySocket = null;

        if (sdk >= 10) {
            try {
                _mySocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("error", "Error creating socket");
            }
        } else {
            try {
                _mySocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("error", "Error creating socket");
            }
        }

        mDevice = device;
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mySocket = _mySocket;

        Log.e("info", "=====>"+mDevice.getName());
        Log.e("info", "=====>"+mDevice.getUuids());
    }

    public void run() {

        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {

            mySocket.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            try {

                mySocket.close();

            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.e("error", ee.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }

    public void cancel () {
        try {
            mySocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using classic bluetooth or BLE??

Comment: @SaravInfern I am using classic bluetooth.